# I am unable to understand the use of map in the following problem code

Tags: python

You have a record of N students. Each record contains the student's name, and their percent marks in Maths, Physics and Chemistry. The marks can be floating values. The user enters some integer N followed by the names and marks for N students. You are required to save the record in a dictionary data type. The user then enters a student's name. Output the average percentage marks obtained by that student, correct to two decimal places.

code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(raw_input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    line = raw_input().split()
    name, scores = line[0], line[1:]
    scores = map(float, scores)
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = raw_input()
query_scores = student_marks[query_name]
print("{0:.2f}".format(sum(query_scores)/(len(query_scores))))
```

I am unable to understand this line: scores = map(float, scores)enter code here

Comment: can you provide input/ output

Comment: Have you asked your teacher, looked in your instructional materials, or Googled "python map"?

Comment: Yes i searched for it on google but the syntax and uses are different from the above mentioned code for map.

Comment: Sample Input 0

3
Krishna 67 68 69
Arjun 70 98 63
Malika 52 56 60
Malika
Sample Output 0

56.00